# Contact Support email with wrong user name

Tags: support, email, contact

I've used the form in [Contact Support](https://pm.stackexchange.com/contact) and received an email with what is meant to be my name but written in a wrong way, as you can see in the following image:

[image: wrong name]

**I assume this is a bug**. Nonetheless, it raises a few questions:

- How is that name being generated?
- How can I ensure the message was really meant to be for me and I'm the only user that received that email?
- Is there something I can do to help fix it?

Attentively

tiagoperes

Comment: Do you have your full name entered on your profile? It's at the bottom of the Edit Profile page.

Comment: Yes and it's "Tiago Peres"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The support system merely takes the first part of your email address (everything before the @) and uses it as a name when automatically creating the contact upon receipt of your first email. It is not integrated with our network and does not attempt to determine what your actual display name is on-site.

Since we don't allow end-users to login to the support system itself, it's also not possible for the name to be *changed* after the initial contact has been created without us having to go manually change it. So attempting to fetch "current display name" is probably not a great idea anyways - it will just become wrong again the moment you change it.

---

We previously did not include the user's "name" in the reply, because they were frequently gibberish and meaningless. Think of the people who use things like stackoverflow@example.com and us sending a message that says "Hi stackoverflow" - weird.

But, users who *do* email us directly (not via the contact form) have the name populated properly with what was is sent in via the email headers. Direct email is more common among our paid products, where addressing the user by name in a reply is a common courtesy and helps personalize the email, which is why it was turned on. Unfortunately we cannot turn it on/off selectively based on the type of support request.